# How do I use font awesome in Gitbook?

Tags: font-awesome, gitbook

I noticed that font awesome is integrated into Gitbook. We have the following files under `_book/gitbook/fonts/fontawesome/`,

```
FontAwesome.otf  
fontawesome-webfont.eot  
fontawesome-webfont.svg  
fontawesome-webfont.ttf  
fontawesome-webfont.woff  
fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

I add an icon,  say `<i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>`, to a markdown file, however, the icon didn't show up as shown below.

[image]

How can I use awesome font in Gitbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitBook doesn't support all awesome icon fonts. It would work using icons from [Font Awesome Free's Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet).